# If a contact changes Membership Type should contacts who inherit that membership also show the new membership type

Tags: civimember, relationships

Scenario: Orgs can pay for a 1 year or 5 year membership.

Org X pays for 1 year. Their Employee Q gains the membership 'by relationship'.

Next year Org X pays for a 5 year membership. Employee Q's membership end date updates correctly ie shows to be 5 years hence, BUT it still shows their Membership Type as a 1 year membership, which imo is incorrect and results in them showing in Smart Groups when they should not.

QuickFix #1 is to delete the relationship, recreate it, and hey presto, Q now shows as having a 5 year membership.

Anyone else had that experience? Bug? Missing 'feature'?